# Still displayed login page after session start

Tags: php

when user login in successfully I have a session start and also it redirects the user to his dashboard

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['login']          = true;
$_SESSION['firstname']      = $row['firstname'];
$_SESSION['surname']        = $row['surname'];
$location = strtolower($row['role']);
header("location: ../$location/");
```

but when ever the user return to the login page or click on the login page the page is still visible to him. how would i make it in such a way that when there is session start already when user try to go to the login page or enter the login page url it should automatically redirects him back to the dashboard untill he logsout of the website he will be able to view the login page.

Comment: Are you using Cakephp Framework?

Comment: No, it is a core PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can check it with an IF construct !!

```
if (isset($_SESSION['login']) && !empty($_SESSION['login'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['login'] === true) {
        // Redirect
        die("<script>window.location.href = 'location_to_another_page'</script>");
    } else {
        // Set Login Information
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but however when user logout it doesn't show the login page anymore it displays "localhost/rsms////////////////////" in the URL or even blank even if you try to access the page it still display the same link. here is my logout page may be the problem is from it. session_start(); session_destroy(); $_SESSION['login'] = false; header("location:../");

Comment: Why do you close the session and set a Session key to false?

Comment: i should not do so?

Comment: it is the logout page that contains that. should I not do so?

Answer (score 0):

First check that user session exist or not, if exist then redirect to as per where you want otherwise display error like "You have not logged in" and do stuff for login process.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['login']) && empty($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION['login'] === false) {
    header("location: redirect_to_login_path");
}else{
    header("location: redirect_to_dashboard_path");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however when user logout it doesn't show the login page anymore it displays "http://localhost/rsms/////////////////////" in the URL even if you try to access the page it still display the same link. here is my logout page may be the problem is from it. session_start();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION['login'] = false;
header("location:../");